# Javascript Compare two arrays based on partial match and update to fully match

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex

I'm working on a project in Node.js (Foundry Virtual Table Top), and I have two arrays. First is a list of entries, the second is the same list, but with indexing numbers prefixed to it. I need to match the two, based on the name, and update the first list to include the same numbering.

Example of 1st list:

- Early Life
- Circumstances of Birth
- Family
- Region
- ...

Example of 2nd list:

- 1.3. Early Life
- 1.3.1. Circumstances of Birth
- 1.3.2. Family
- 1.3.3. Region

**So I want "Early Life" to be updated to "1.3. Early Life"**

I have the base of it done, along with the regex I need, but I'm not sure how to actually compare, match, and then update based on the partial matches. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have very little experience with javascript.

```js
/** Takes a compendium of journals and matches then replaces names to those of an imported list prepended with index numbers
* New naming convention == "#.##... TEXT"
* Eg. "Special Abilities" -> "2.01.2. Special Abilities"
* 
* 1. put the new name list in an array
* 2. iterate through the compendium, get index or contents
* 3. compare the entries name value vs new list(array), regex'd to remove the #s and . prior to the name, and set an update array with the new name
* 4. update the compendium
*/

//read text file of new names
let f = await fetch("/test_list.txt")
let txt =  await f.text()

// Convert to array, split by line
let updatedNames =  txt.toString().split("\n");

// Compendium to Update
const compendiumLabel = "Gamemastery";

(async ()=>{
  const p = game.packs.entries.find(e => e.metadata.label === compendiumLabel)

  // Array of current journal entries (filtering out Compendium Folders)
  const currentNames = p.index.filter(x => x.name != '#[CF_tempEntity]').map(i=>{
    return { name : i.name };
  });

  // Compare currentNames to updatedNames (regex'd to remove starting numbers and .)

  // regex that excludes the numbering "#.#.#. " from updatedNames
  let regex = new RegExp('[^(\d+.)+\s].*', 'g')


  // update compendium

})();
```

Comment: You seem to want to remove dot-separated numbers at the start of string. Use `const updatedNames = currentNames.map(x => x.replace(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?\s*/, ''))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, I want to ADD the numbers from the second list to the first list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```js
const notIndexed = `Early Life
Circumstances of Birth
Family
Region`.split('\n');

const indexed = `1.3. Early Life
1.3.1. Circumstances of Birth
1.3.2. Family
1.3.3. Region`.split('\n');

const regexp = /^((?:\d.)+) +(.+)/;

const mapping = new Map(
  indexed.map((line) => {
    const [, index, title] = line.match(regexp);
    return [title, index];
  })
);

const reIndexed = notIndexed.map(
  (line) => {
    if (mapping.has(line)) return `${mapping.get(line)} ${line}`;
    return line;
  }
).join('\n');

console.log(reIndexed);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting that to implement. The lists I am using has ~600+ items, so i'm using arrays. The mapping is showing as undefined, and nothing prints to console